# How to make the HTML tags unclickeable for e.target?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm using the following code to get the ID of the anchor link:

**HTML:**

```
<a id="{{_id}}" class="clearfix" href="#">
  <img src="/avatar.png"/>
  <div>{{username}}</div>
</a>
```

**JS:**

```
 'click a': function(e) {
    var currentEditorId = $(e.target).attr('id')

    console.log(currentEditorId)
  }
```

It works OK. The problem arises when I click on the `img` and `div` tag directly (the anchor tag is spread above them).

How can I make it so that `e.target` only captures the anchor tag and not the HTML tags that are inside?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find the `a` tag using [.closest()](http://api.jquery.com/closest/)

```
var currentEditorId = $(e.target).closest('a').attr('id')
```

Or try to use the `this` reference since `this` in the event handler will refer to the element which was targeted by the event

```
var currentEditorId = this.id
```

But Looks like you are using some kind of framework like `backbone` so I don't know whether it will work

Answer (score 1):

You can try doing the following. But, like Arun said, it seems that you're using Backbone, so I am not very sure if it will work.

```
'click a': function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation()
    var currentEditorId = $(e.target).attr('id')
    console.log(currentEditorId)
}
```